# set sys.path for Python IDLE

Tags: python

**How do I set sys.path** for Python IDLE sessions?

I have tried adding a path to python path in `.bashrc` but this had no effect within IDLE when I tested it with using `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.bashrc` is read when bash is launched. Starting IDLE directly does not launch bash. If you launch IDLE from a terminal running bash you will see that it will be present.

Comment: But I used source ~/.bashrc,didn't that matter?

Comment: Of course that matters. *For the shell you run it in.*

Comment: I don't quite understand.I thought when I used source ~/.bashrc,the pythonpath in the whole _system_ would change...So you are saying even if I reboot,the path wouldn't output in IDLE if I wouldn't launch it from the shell?

Comment: If you reboot then yes, since bash is run as part of the login sequence.

Comment: Ehh,what's the different between being run when logining and being run as in `source ~/.bashrc`,not the same thing?!

Comment: Nothing. Until you try to run something else.